# Utilizing solenoids in electric motors

Tags: motors, electromagnetism

I have seen videos of solenoid engines but there were claims that they were inefficient unlike DC motors. I was wondering what would be the most efficient use of a solenoid in an electric motor. Thanks!

Comment: Take it apart and use the windings for a traditional DC motor. What "videos" are you talking about?

Comment: Can you please update the post to include the video's?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "solenoid" engines will be that they are by nature turning reciprocating motion to rotation, and therefore will be less efficient.  Turning electricity into force & thus motion will always be the same, whether it be a regular motor, piston motors like this, or rail-guns.  So the determining factor is both cost/complexity and mechanical system losses.